# Checking for Whether Both Expression Strings Contain the Variable

Tags: java, string, if-statement, contains, boolean-expression

I had made a fully functioning method that would grab a variable string like *x* or *var* for the equation as so:

```java
// Equation Variable Getter
    public String getVar(){
        String variable = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < getEquation().length(); i++){
            if ((getEquation().charAt(i) >= 65 && getEquation().charAt(i) <= 90)
            || (getEquation().charAt(i) >= 97 && getEquation().charAt(i) <= 122)){
                variable += getEquation().charAt(i);
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(variable);
        return variable;
    }
```

While attempting to solve an equation like *x = x* or *num = num*, I split the sides into an array and trimmed the whitespaces like any other equation that I had tested. The problem was in comparing the two sides. Naturally, I used an if statement and compared them like so:

```
if (sides[0].contains(getVar()) && sides[1].contains(getVar()){
   // statements used to solve equation format co*var = co*var
}
```

When using this on *x = x* and *var = var*, the if statement never ran. Upon further investigation, I found out that the code did went around it because both of the conditions in the statement were false. This was not supposed to happen as, for strings like *x = x* and *var = var*, both did contain the variable *x*

Is there something wrong with the if statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This will be easier for us with a [mre].

Comment: I would send in the method that has the if statement, but the method itself has almost 200 lines, which is very long and has most parts functional by itself and irrelevant to the question above.

Comment: You are correct, posting 200 lines of code would be no good idea. This is as good a time as any to train creating a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: if there are more variables in your equation, how does `getVar()` know, which one to take? Your current implementation simply concatenates all letter characters from `getEquation()` into one long string, so `x=x` would be processed to `xx`.

Comment: @cyberbrain Thank you so much for finding the bug! The getVar() method does in fact perform that way, so I have to overload the method to take in a string parameter, which would be either one of the sides, in order for the if statement to pass and solve the equation as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I need to thank the people that have assisted with finding the solution to this problem. Apparently, there was, in fact, an issue with the getVar() method getting double variables from equation strings with multiple instances of the variable.

What I did to resolve the issue was to overload the getVar() method to take in and use string parameters so that I can get the variable from just one side of the equation.

The solve() method, which contains the if statement, worked to solve equations that would have **1** or more variables on either side. So, in the cases through which only 1 side would contain the variable, the both getVar() methods would still be used to avoid an *IndexOutOfBoundsException*.